# how to set Hardware button behavoir Ionic 4 Android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4, angular8

I'm working on a Ionic 4 application , currently on android device when i click the hardware back button from any page it will always goes to the root page .

Exemple : Home -> PAGE1 -> PAGE2 => CLick hardware back button => Home

i want the back button to lead to previous page and exit app if i'm in Home page

Answer (score 0):

Please share what you have tried until now and what is causing the issue?